# show jSON data in google maps marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show several markers in my google maps. Each marker has a pop-up with some informations. I get the information by a database. But I don't get the info in the pop-up:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
var info = "";
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://server:8080/getInfo", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, f) {
            info = "<tr>" + "<td> Info: " + f.address + " / " + f.date + "</td>" + "</tr>";
            $(info).appendTo("#info");
        });
    });
});

var contentString2 = 
    '<div id="content">'+
        '<h2>Barcelona</h2>'+
        '<div>' +info+ '</div>'+
        '<p><a href="#contact" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Contact</a></a> '+
        '</p>'+
    '</div>';               


// marker
var parkingList = [
    ['Spain', contentString1, 41.469326, 1.489334, 1],
    ['Barcelona', contentString2, 41.353812, 2.157440, 2]
],...
```

Now, I have to questions:

1. How can I insert the data from my json into the contentString?
2. How can I create a variable, which includes the json data and can be used in the whole JavaScript and not only in the getJSON function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can declare a variable before calling function to pull json and use it anywhere in your script. Please note, it will be assigned value only after `getJson` is called.

2) I have shown example how to insert data from json into the contentString.

```
var alldata,contentString = "";
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://server:8080/getInfo", function(data) {
        alldata = data; //stores json
        $.each(data, function(i, f) {
            contentString += "<tr>" + "<td> Info: " + f.address + " / " + f.date + "</td>" + "</tr>";
            $(contentString).appendTo("#info");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I've changed my code, but it doesn't work. Can you have a look at it?

Comment: @Struct I have already mentioned in answer "Please note, it will be assigned value only after getJson is called." Statement `var contentString2 = '<div id="content">........` is executed before json returns value. If you execute it after `getjson` completes its execution, it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to execute the statement AFTER getJSON. I've tried it with callback, but that doesn't work.