# JSON feed on Google map is showing nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I want the Google map show marker with JSON feeds. but it's not working. I can't find the actual problem. so here is my code:

```js
 var map;

// The JSON data
var json = [{  
   "OpperationErrorMsg":"",
   "IsSuccess":true,
   "ResultId":1000,
   "Timestamp":"2016-10-12T18:00:07.0232702Z",
   "Echo":null,
   "InSandbox":true,
   "DebugMessages":[  

   ],
   "MissingDetails":[  

   ],
   "ResponseData":[  
      {  
         "CallTimeLocal":"2016-10-10T06:28:48.7330000",
         "IncidentId":3374,
         "IncidentNumber":"HC2016004034",
         "CallTime":"2016-10-10T10:28:48.7330000",
         "ElapsedSeconds":0,
         "Location":"2712 E HANNA AVE",
         "BuildingName":null,
         "BuildingNumber":null,
         "NatureId":6743,
         "FirePriorityId":1,
         "CoordinateX":-82.429500000000,
         "CoordinateY":28.003389000000
      },
      {  
         "CallTimeLocal":"2016-10-10T11:28:36.7000000",
         "IncidentId":3382,
         "IncidentNumber":"HC2016004042",
         "CallTime":"2016-10-10T15:28:36.7000000",
         "ElapsedSeconds":0,
         "Location":"1220 APOLLO BEACH BLVD S",
         "BuildingName":"Apollo Beach Marina",
         "BuildingNumber":null,
         "NatureId":8035,
         "FirePriorityId":1,
         "CoordinateX":-82.422369000000,
         "CoordinateY":27.781254000000
      },
      {  
         "CallTimeLocal":"2016-10-10T14:29:59.8830000",
         "IncidentId":3387,
         "IncidentNumber":"HC2016004047",
         "CallTime":"2016-10-10T18:29:59.8830000",
         "ElapsedSeconds":0,
         "Location":"9600 SHELDONWOOD RD",
         "BuildingName":null,
         "BuildingNumber":null,
         "NatureId":6420,
         "FirePriorityId":12,
         "CoordinateX":-82.580530000000,
         "CoordinateY":28.034779000000
      },
      {  
         "CallTimeLocal":"2016-10-10T15:27:37.7270000",
         "IncidentId":3389,
         "IncidentNumber":"HC2016004049",
         "CallTime":"2016-10-10T19:27:37.7270000",
         "ElapsedSeconds":0,
         "Location":"4691 GALLAGHER RD",
         "BuildingName":"Strawberry Crest High School",
         "BuildingNumber":null,
         "NatureId":7873,
         "FirePriorityId":2,
         "CoordinateX":-82.236450000000,
         "CoordinateY":28.021233000000
      }
   ],
   "CurrentStatusData":null
}];



function initialize() {
  
  // Giving the map som options
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.0,-80.0)
  };
  
  // Creating the map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  
  
  // Looping through all the entries from the JSON data
  for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    
    // Current object
    var obj = json[i];

    // Adding a new marker for the object
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj.CoordinateY,obj.CoordinateX),
      map: map,
        draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

      title: obj.BuildingName // this works, giving the marker a title with the correct title
    });
    
    // Adding a new info window for the object
    var clicker = addClicker(marker, obj.title);

  } // end loop
  
  
  // Adding a new click event listener for the object
  function addClicker(marker, content) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      
      if (infowindow) {infowindow.close();}
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      
    });
  }
  
}

// Initialize the map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
   <script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

I will be using it on a HTML page. Though the JSON data will be updated automatically so i can't change the JSON Arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? This appears to be just random snippets of it. e.g. Where is your request for the JSON file happening? Where is your reference to the google maps API script? (You have one for jquery 2.1.1, but not Google Maps) Where is the rest of your mapOptions object? Where is the initialize function that you're referencing in you window.load event? etc.

Comment: Hey Steve, I have updated the post and that's all what i have got right now. I hope that can be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found these problems in your code:

- In your loop where you create each marker, you are looping over the `json` array. However, this is not your array of marker data. `json[0]` is your main object, and `json[0].ResponseData` is the marker array that you need to loop over. So I put that value in a variable named `responses` and looped over that instead. I don't know if the JSON data could have more than one object in its outermost array; if it does you would need an outer loop to handle those. For now I assumed there is just one outer object addressed with `json[0]`.
- When you call `addClicker` you pass in `obj.title` which doesn't exist. Presumably you meant `obj.BuildingName`.
- Your click handler references a variable called `infowindow`, but on the first click that variable does not exist and causes an error. So I declared `infowindow` as a global window.

So, how did I find these problems? Using the JavaScript debugger. Normally I would add a `debugger;` statement at the beginning of the `initialize()` function and single step through the code to see what is going on. This would reveal that where the main loop sets `var obj = json[i];` it isn't getting the expected value.

That works great on a normal web page, but it doesn't seem to work well in the embedded snippet here on SO. (The debugger shows the wrong source line.) So instead I started adding `console.log();` statements where it looked like things might be going wrong, such as `console.log( 'obj:', obj );` immediately after the `var obj =` assignment.

Also, it's nice to automatically zoom and center the map according to where the markers are located. I added a bit of code using a `LatLngBounds` which is extended for each marker, and then a `map.fitBounds()` after all the markers are created. If you do that you don't need to explicitly zoom and center the map when first creating it, so I removed those. (Otherwise the map is displayed at one position and then repositioned.)

One caveat with the `fitBounds()`: if there were *no* markers, then the map wouldn't get displayed at all. To handle that case you would want to check for the case where `responses.length` is zero and call `map.setZoom()` and `map.setCenter()` with default values.

I marked the changed lines with `////` to make them easy to find:

```js
 var map, infowindow; ////

// The JSON data
var json = [{  
   "OpperationErrorMsg":"",
   "IsSuccess":true,
   "ResultId":1000,
   "Timestamp":"2016-10-12T18:00:07.0232702Z",
   "Echo":null,
   "InSandbox":true,
   "DebugMessages":[  

   ],
   "MissingDetails":[  

   ],
   "ResponseData":[  
      {  
         "CallTimeLocal":"2016-10-10T06:28:48.7330000",
         "IncidentId":3374,
         "IncidentNumber":"HC2016004034",
         "CallTime":"2016-10-10T10:28:48.7330000",
         "ElapsedSeconds":0,
         "Location":"2712 E HANNA AVE",
         "BuildingName":null,
         "BuildingNumber":null,
         "NatureId":6743,
         "FirePriorityId":1,
         "CoordinateX":-82.429500000000,
         "CoordinateY":28.003389000000
      },
      {  
         "CallTimeLocal":"2016-10-10T11:28:36.7000000",
         "IncidentId":3382,
         "IncidentNumber":"HC2016004042",
         "CallTime":"2016-10-10T15:28:36.7000000",
         "ElapsedSeconds":0,
         "Location":"1220 APOLLO BEACH BLVD S",
         "BuildingName":"Apollo Beach Marina",
         "BuildingNumber":null,
         "NatureId":8035,
         "FirePriorityId":1,
         "CoordinateX":-82.422369000000,
         "CoordinateY":27.781254000000
      },
      {  
         "CallTimeLocal":"2016-10-10T14:29:59.8830000",
         "IncidentId":3387,
         "IncidentNumber":"HC2016004047",
         "CallTime":"2016-10-10T18:29:59.8830000",
         "ElapsedSeconds":0,
         "Location":"9600 SHELDONWOOD RD",
         "BuildingName":null,
         "BuildingNumber":null,
         "NatureId":6420,
         "FirePriorityId":12,
         "CoordinateX":-82.580530000000,
         "CoordinateY":28.034779000000
      },
      {  
         "CallTimeLocal":"2016-10-10T15:27:37.7270000",
         "IncidentId":3389,
         "IncidentNumber":"HC2016004049",
         "CallTime":"2016-10-10T19:27:37.7270000",
         "ElapsedSeconds":0,
         "Location":"4691 GALLAGHER RD",
         "BuildingName":"Strawberry Crest High School",
         "BuildingNumber":null,
         "NatureId":7873,
         "FirePriorityId":2,
         "CoordinateX":-82.236450000000,
         "CoordinateY":28.021233000000
      }
   ],
   "CurrentStatusData":null
}];

function initialize() {
  
  // Giving the map som options
  var mapOptions = {
    ////
  };
  
  // Creating the map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); ////
  
  // Looping through all the entries from the JSON data
  var responses = json[0].ResponseData; ////
  for(var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) { ////
    
    // Current object
    var obj = responses[i]; ////

    // Adding a new marker for the object
    var position =
      new google.maps.LatLng( obj.CoordinateY, obj.CoordinateX ); ////
    bounds.extend( position ); ////
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position, ////
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: obj.BuildingName
    });
    
    // Adding a new info window for the object
    var clicker = addClicker(marker, obj.BuildingName); ////

  } // end loop
  
  map.fitBounds( bounds ); ////
  
  // Adding a new click event listener for the object
  function addClicker(marker, content) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      
      if (infowindow) {infowindow.close();}
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      
    });
  }
  
}

// Initialize the map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
   <script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: This is a better answer than that one that I posted. Deleted my answer and I defer to this one. Kudos for `bounds`.

Comment: @Steve: thanks for the kind words. Yes, that `map.fitBounds()` thing is one of my favorite tricks - it makes it so easy to automatically zoom and center a map.

Comment: Learned something new today! Didn't know that was available in the API.  I've been doing it a much harder way. Now I need to go refactor some code with my new trick. ;)

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, But i got one more question to ask. If i want to load the Json file from an external server then how i am going to load the variables? I have tried it with .getjson but i got stuck.

Comment: Use the callback function that `$.getJSON()` provides. The callback function is where you have access to the JSON data. There are some examples on the `$.getJSON()` [doc page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). The code snippet near the top of the page is a good example: see how it references the `data` variable inside the success callback? That's the JSON data downloaded from the server, and this is where you would initialize your markers. Maybe post a new question if you still have trouble, but feel free to @ me here with a link to the new question.

Comment: @Michael. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063686/calling-json-file-form-external-sources?noredirect=1#comment67401391_40063686

Comment: @Geary i have posted another question on the same topic today. couldn't sort the problem. So, If you wanna look at there it would be very help for me. So, Here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977806/show-json-data-in-google-maps-marker