# Calling json file from external sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used this JavaScript to call my JSON data from an external source. The json data will load from server. So, what will be the script that I can get the markers from google map using the external JSON data.

```js
 var map, infowindow; ////

// The JSON data
var json = "http://www.tripleclickstudio.com/json/file.json"
$.getJSON(json,{
    tags:"location",
    tagmode:"any",
    format:"json"
    
})

function initialize() {
  
  // Giving the map som options
  var mapOptions = {
    ////
  };
  
  // Creating the map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); ////
  
  // Looping through all the entries from the JSON data
  var responses = json[0].ResponseData; ////
  for(var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) { ////
    
    // Current object
    var obj = responses[i]; ////

    // Adding a new marker for the object
    var position =
      new google.maps.LatLng( obj.CoordinateY, obj.CoordinateX ); ////
    bounds.extend( position ); ////
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position, ////
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: obj.BuildingName
    });
    
    // Adding a new info window for the object
    var clicker = addClicker(marker, obj.BuildingName); ////

  } // end loop
  
  map.fitBounds( bounds ); ////
  
  // Adding a new click event listener for the object
  function addClicker(marker, content) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      
      if (infowindow) {infowindow.close();}
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      
    });
  }
  
}

// Initialize the map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
   <script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

But the output is noting but a blank page. but if I use the JSON data into the file this works perfectly.

Comment: `var json` is a url string. Study some ajax tutorials  and read the getJSON docs. Need to understand how ajax works first

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054374) and as geocodezip describes below, you need to pass a callback function into the `$.getJSON()` call. That function will receive a parameter that contains your JSON data, and that's where you need to do your map/marker initialization using that data. There are several examples in the `$.getJSON` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/); the second code snippet from the top has a `$.getJSON()` call with a callback function that you can use as an example.

Comment: Also note that the JSON data in your test file is not in the same format as your test JSON in the original question. The test data there had the entire JSON object wrapped inside `[]` making it an array containing a single element that is the actual object. The JSON file on your server does not have that outer `[]` (and this make much more sense not having the outer `[]`). So once you get the data downloaded, where we were doing things like `json[0].ResponseData` it should simply be `json.ResponseData` (assuming you use the name `json` for the parameter to your callback function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get two javascript errors in your code snippet:

1. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.tripleclickstudio.com/json/file.json?tags=location&tagmode=any&format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`
2. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` on this line:

```
for(var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
```

Because responses doesn't exist when you are running the loop.  $.getJSON is asynchronous, the data isn't populated until the callback function is run (which you haven't defined).  Your first problem, however, is that there is a security policy preventing you from downloading it with $.getJSON.  You either need to get permission to download it for your domain (the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header) or to download it via JSONP.

However, when I do that, I get a syntax error in your JSON.

Comment: The JSON format itself seems OK - I pasted the test file into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it validated without errors. You are right on the money with the other comments, as usual. :-) Also see [OP's original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054374) for more context.